# What's "Listen To Registration Events"in Marketing cloud iOS SDK guide?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I'm trying to configure the Contact Key Registration SDK in Mobile Push.

I understand the process that delays registration until a contact key is set by the application, so that we can avoid double counting the contacts.

However, the Android Guide and iOS Guide are different.

In the iOS Guide, I can find "Listen To Registration Events," but it is not mentioned in the Android Guide.
The iOS Guide says, "Register a callback that will be notified when Registration-related events happen. You can also unregister a callback once the callback has been triggered." Honestly, I'm having difficulty understanding this explanation.

My questions are:

1. What is "Listen To Registration Events" for?
2. Why doesn't Android require that step?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android SDK also supports this functionality, refer to the doc [here](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/javadocs/MarketingCloudSdk/8.0/com.salesforce.marketingcloud.registration/-registration-manager/register-for-registration-events.html).

Register a `registrationEventListener` that will be notified when Registration related events happen.

Listen To Registration Events - if the customer application wants to see the updated registration payload in the Mobile Push SDK, they can listen for this events. This is completely optional to implement.